# I am getting an error trying to read a CSV file in to a List<int> c#

Tags: c#

*I'm sorry if my question doesn't make sense. This is a school assignment and we were tasked to use a CSV file into list but we were never taught how or discussed anything like this so I am a bit confused and have to learn it myself.*

I am getting this error while trying my code:

> rror CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Here's my code:

```
public static List<string> questions = new List<string>();
public static List<string> answers = new List<string>();
public static List<int> points = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"TriviaQuestions.csv"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                questions.Add(values[0]);
                answers.Add(values[1]);
                points = int.Parse(values[2]);
            }             
            Console.WriteLine(questions[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(answers[0]);
        }  
    }
```

I am trying to read out the contents within my CSV file which is seperate by ','.
I was tasked to make the question and answer as a list of string and have the points as a list of int and I am having a bit of problem trying to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

points is a `List<int>` type, but `int.Parse` returns int (obviously). I guess you want `points.Add(int.Parse(values[2]))`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome - marks as answer/upvote always appreciated ;)

Comment: @see sharper Forget a `)`?